# Why is multiple regression to be preferred over simple linear regression?

Tags: regression, self-study, multiple-regression

How does a multiple regression differ from a simple linear regression and why is the use of a multiple regression generally preferred over a simple linear regression?

Comment: Is this a quiz or home work?

Comment: Homework discussion

Comment: Please read the `[self-study]` tag's
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: You might enjoy challenging the implicit premise that multiple regression should be preferred over simple regression. In fact, many of the standard tests performed routinely with multiple regression are there specifically to see whether the exists sufficient evidence to use multiple regression instead of simple regression (or no regression at all), which effectively turns this premise on its head.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple regression allows you to use information from several variables *simultaneuosly*. Imagine that you built two separate simple regression models - one uses height to predict weight and the other uses age to predict weight. Now, imagine you have a 15 year old who is 5"8'. Your age model predicts he weighs 120 lbs and your height model predicts he weighs 140 lbs. Well, which should you believe? If you built a multiple regression model you could use both the age and height information simultaneously to get a single, optimal prediction for this individual's weight.